# Select MYSQL data (words) that contain certain characters

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a dictionary in an MYSQL table, the table consists of 240 000 words. If I for example have the letters *G*, *I*, *G*, *S*, *N* and *O* I would like to select all the words in the table that contain all or some of these letters (and no other letters).

Acceptable words would for example include:

- going
- song
- son
- so
- on

Examples of unacceptable words:

- songs (one S more than allowed)
- words longer that the number of characters (6 in this case)

What would the MYSQL query look like?

My current MYSQL looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `list` 
WHERE word like '%S%' and word like '%O%' and word like '%G%'
```

I want to use 6 or 7 letters and find words that are:

- equally long
- shorter

Now I only find words that are equally long or longer and that contain other letters as well.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve], see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. Also add the SQL queries you have tried and explain why they didn't return the result you want.

Comment: Can you change the layout of the tables to create new columns? Can you even add a new table for additional information? This problem is loosely related to "saving comma separated values", even though no commas are involved here. As seen on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad it is very difficult to handle such kind of data, as you already have noticed.

Comment: I don't understand what you want with "6 or 7 ..." -- give some examples, and I may further enhance my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a starting point:

(I will insist that you construct the query from the letters you desire.)

If the column has only one word:

```
WHERE word REGEXP '^[GISNO]+$'
```

If the column can have multiple words, this will pick the row (but not the word), then before version 8.0:

```
WHERE word REGEXP '[[:<:]][GISNO]+[[:>:]]'
```

Or, with 8.0:

```
WHERE word REGEXP '\b[GISNO]+b'
```

Now to filter out "too many" of each letter.  (I will assume the word is by itself in the column.)

```
  AND word NOT REGEXP 'G.*G.*G'   -- max of 2 Gs
  AND word NOT REGEXP 'I.*I'      -- max of 1 I
  AND word NOT REGEXP 'O.*O'      -- max of 1 O
  AND word NOT REGEXP 'S.*S'      -- max of 1 S
```

Another approach involves building an extra column with the letters alphabetized.

```
going   ggino
song    gnos
son     nos
so      os
on      no
no      no   -- note the dup in the new column
```

Now the test becomes

```
WHERE sorted_word REGEXP '^g{0,2}i?n?o?s?$'
```

This should run somewhat faster.

And some other things may run faster using this trick.